# How to get float from file using getc() in C?

Tags: c, char, type-conversion, int, getc

I have a file with ";" as a separator, i want to get some characters and save them as float, I've come up with something like this:

```
int c;
char help[10];
float x;
while(getc(c)!=';'){
strcpy(help, c);
}
float = atof(help);
```

Comment: What (if anything) is wrong with "this"?

Comment: Why would you not use `fscanf()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct usage of `getc`. It is `int getc(FILE *stream)`. So you need to provide the `stream` from which it reads.

```
while(getc(c)!=';'){ <-- wrong
   strcpy(help, c);  <-- wrong
   ...
```

is wrong. The second parameter to `strcpy` should be a nul termnated `char` array.

```
char cs[]={c,0}
strcpy(help,cs);
```

or even better<sup>alk suggested</sup>

```
{strcpy(help, (char[2]){c});}
```

About the input part you can do this though:

```
 while((c=getc(stdin))!=';'){ 
   ...
```

Instead of using `atof` it is much better to use `strtof` or `strtod` functions. They provide error checking unlike these `ato*` functions.

Comment: I'd prefer to use `{ strcpy(help, (char[2]){c}); }` :-)

Comment: Note the curly braces around the statement to limit the life time of the compound literal.

Comment: @alk.: The thing is my earlier solution also is taking the benefit of the curly braces..yes I get it.  If I dont put it...then it;s life time will be depend on that of the nearest enclosing block.

Comment: "*They provide extended error checking.*" only those functions provide **complete** error checking.

Comment: @alk.: Yes...these don't provide at all.